# A question about expanding complex functions of real arguments

Tags: symbolic, complex, arithmetic

I have the following problem. There is such an expression as:

```
P[x_,y_] := z[y] E^(I beta x) + Conjugate[z[y] E^(I beta x)];
```

The variables `x, y, beta` are real but the function `z[y]` is complex. I need to expand `P[x, y]^2`. So I try this:

```
ComplexExpand[P[x, y]^2, z[y]]
```

The output contains Re[z[y]], Im[z[y]], Cos[...] and Sin[...]. In my case, I need the output to be like this:

```
z[y]^2 E(2 I beta x) + 2 z[y] Conjugate[z[y]] + Conjugate[z[y]]^2 E^(-2 I beta x)
```

What should I change in my approach? I have already tried TrigToExpand, FullSimplify and Hold but I did not get the desirable result.

Comment: You can get rid of the `Re` and `Im` by using the option `TargetFunctions->{Conjugate}`. But that still gives `Sin` and `Cos` for the exponential functions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following gives what you intended:

```
Refine[Expand[P[x, y]^2], (x|y|beta) \[Element] Reals]
(*
==> Conjugate[z[y]]^2/E^((2*I)*beta*x) + 2*Conjugate[z[y]]*z[y] + 
     E^((2*I)*beta*x)*z[y]^2
*)
```

In cases where you can live with expansion of complex exponentials into `Sin` and `Cos` you can also use

```
ComplexExpand[P[x, y]^2, z[y], TargetFunctions->{Conjugate}]
(*
==> Conjugate[z[y]]^2*Cos[beta*x]^2 - (2*I)*Conjugate[z[y]]^2*Cos[beta*x]*
      Sin[beta*x] - Conjugate[z[y]]^2*Sin[beta*x]^2 + 
     2*Conjugate[z[y]]*Cos[beta*x]^2*z[y] + 2*Conjugate[z[y]]*Sin[beta*x]^2*
      z[y] + Cos[beta*x]^2*z[y]^2 + (2*I)*Cos[beta*x]*Sin[beta*x]*z[y]^2 - 
     Sin[beta*x]^2*z[y]^2
*)
```

Comment: Nice one. I think the question title is misleading b/c the problem isn't about `ComplexExpand[]` but about expressing a Complex expression in terms of certain things. Can you find a better title? I'm not sure about the better option.

Comment: @celtschk Thank you a lot!

Comment: @belisarius I agree with you that the title does not express the very problem. I will rename it.